# Get CGRect from UIKit UIView to use with .position modifier from SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiview, uikit

So basically I need to grab the exact position of a UIView (CGRect frame) and present a UIHostingController wrapping a SwiftUI View that draws an overlay over said frame (with the help of the .position modifier).

Im currently grabbing the frame of the UIView doing something basic like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if !isLoading {
        let frameToDrawOverlayOn = buttonView.frame
        delegate?.presentOverlay(frame: frameToDrawOverlayOn)
    }
}
```

The presentOverlayMethod just presents the overlay:

```
func presentOverlay(frame: CGRect) {
    let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: OverlayView(testFrame: frame))
    vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    view?.present(vc, animated: false)
}
```

And the overlay is just:

```
struct OverlayView: View {
    
    let testFrame: CGRect
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .stroke(.purple, lineWidth: 4)
                .frame(width: testFrame.width, height: testFrame.height)
                .position(x: testFrame.midX, y: testFrame.midY)
        }
    }
}
```

For whatever reason the positioning of the RoundedRectangle is not correct as it is not above the desired UIView. My guess is its because im grabbing the frame of the UIView which gives me the position of the view but in relation to its parent, how can I make it so I can grab the frame that actually works with the swiftui position modifier so the RoundedRectangle is exactly above the UIView.